# My php/apache2 page doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

I'm learning PHP with Apache2, so I set up my virtual hosts but I receive "Server not found"

**My douglaslearning.com.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin diasdasilvadouglas12@gmail.com
    ServerName www.douglaslearning.com
    ServerAlias www.douglaslearning.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/douglaslearning.com/public_html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<Directory "/var/www/douglaslearning.com/public_html">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        Require all granted
        AllowOverride All
</Directory>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

**my hosts file:**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   www.douglaslearning.com/
```

I type the all required commands!

Comment: remove the `/` in your hosts file, restart your DNS responder, and apache2. Try to ping www.douglaslearning.com, should work

Comment: What a newbie error,thanks man,its works!